# C++ line output

Tags: c++

```
cout << boolalpha ("1" < "0") << endl;
```

I was compiling this recently as a spin off from some course work I was doing. Why does this produce `true` when I execute it?

```
cout << boolalpha (string("1") < string("0")) << endl;
```

does the comparison as expected.

Comment: What did you expect it to produce, and why?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! "… this produce true … does the comparison as expected." That's funny. In C++ both of your program fragments [produce syntax errors](http://ideone.com/Js1YC) since `std::boolalpha` [doesn't take `bool` as a parameter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha). Please don't post code from memory, the errors in your code detract from the question in your post. Please copy-and-paste your code directly from your program into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's comparing `const char*`, the result of `"1"` and `"0"` is undefined by the standard, whereas the comparison of 2 `std::string`s is defined and your output in that case is expected.

Quick case in point:

```
char* y = "0";
char* x = "1";
std::cout << (x<y) << endl;
    //output 1 on my platform
```

and

```
char* x = "1";
char* y = "0";
std::cout << (x<y) << endl;
    //output 0 on my platform
```

I'm specifying "on my platform" because there's no standard rule (but it can be a compiler rule) to where the pointers are created or in which order they are created.

In my case, the addresses are assigned in reverse order of declaration.

I'm willing to bet that if you run:

```
cout << ("1" < "0") << endl;
```

and

```
cout << ("0" < "1") << endl;
```

you'd get the same output (although it's not a rule). Note that you should run them in different instances of the program. If you run them in the same instance, you might get different results, as string literals reside in a single place in memory.

Comment: I'm willing to bet that `boolapha("1" < "0")` won't compile.

Comment: @Robᵩ maybe his compiler isn't standard-compliant. For me, it also doesn't compile, that's why in my code snippet I didn't use boolalpha.

Comment: Sorry I made a copying error, it was: cout << boolalpha << ("0" < "1") << endl; I also tried: cout << boolalpha << ("1" < "0") << endl; and got the same result

Comment: @SamKeays I explained everything in my answer. Did you get it?

Answer (score 3):

Expression "1" < "0" compares values of two pointers. One points to character sequence "1" and the other points to character sequence. Your compiler placed character sequences in memory in such a way that address of char sequence "1" is before that of "0".

With strings, however, operator<(const string&, const string&) is called, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are comparing two pointers (the strings `"1"` and `"0"` are represented as arrays of `char`, synonymous (kinda) with pointer to char).  If you want the comparison between the numbers 0 and 1, you don't need the quotes.  Otherwise you need a string comparison function that compares the content of the strings, not their addresses.  Best if you wrap them in an `std::string` and use the `compare()` member function.